# "Desiderare" + infinito: qual è la differenza tra inserire o meno la preposizione "di"?

Tags: word-usage, difference, prepositions

Ho cercato il verbo ["desiderare" sul vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/desiderare/)  perché avevo il dubbio se reggesse o meno la preposizione "di" prima di un infinito ("desiderava di morire" oppure "desiderava morire"?). Ho trovato questa spiegazione di cui non sono sicura di cogliere il senso:

> *desidero parlarti; desidero restare solo* (in questa, e in altre frasi, può essere anche espressione attenuata di una volontà, di un ordine, che diventa più decisa con la prep. *di*: *desidero di restare solo, desidero di non essere disturbato*); *desiderava ardentemente di rivedere la famiglia*

Potreste spiegarmi qual è la differenza tra mettere e non mettere la preposizione "di" in questo tipo di frasi?

Comment: *reggesse* non *reggessi* :)... Personalmente non vedo molta differenza tra *desidero fare qualcosa* o *desidero di fare qualcosa*, qui ci vuole un purista della lingua...

Comment: Concordo che non ci sia differenza di significato. Nota che l'uso della preposizione "di" è meno comune: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=desidero+di+andare%2Cdesidero+andare%2C+desidero+parlare%2C+desidero+di+parlare+&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdesidero%20di%20andare%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdesidero%20andare%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdesidero%20parlare%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdesidero%20di%20parlare%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Un po' di considerazioni “ufficiose” e con qualche citazione, da un altro forum: http://www.achyra.org/cruscate/viewtopic.php?t=991&view=previous

Answer (score 2):

La differenza, come specifica il vocabolario [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/), sta nel grado di enfasi che si vuole dare al desiderio. In altre parole senza l'uso del *di*, il desiderio risulta più attenuato:

> *desidero parlarti*

esprime un desiderio, per fare un confronto di grande aiuto in inglese sarebbe il *"wish"*, mentre

> *desidero di parlarti*

esprime un desiderio con la sfumatura di una volontà, quindi con una condizione più forte, sempre per il paragone con l'inglese corrisponderebbe ad un *"desire"*.

### *Nota personale*

Ovviamente a livello di correttezza formale vanno bene entrambe le forme, tuttavia c'è un'ulteriore sfumatura se ci troviamo in un contesto di lingua parlata.

Il *"di"*, nel parlato, suona un po' ridondante (superfluo, ripetitivo), in quanto non ce ne è un effettivo bisogno, poiché la frase ha senso compiuto e si capisce ugualmente indipendentemente dalla sua presenza.
Un italiano difficilmente direbbe

> *desidero **di** restare solo*

preferirebbe piuttosto la forma senza il ***di***. Infine un'ulteriore sfumatura è da trovarsi nella presenza dopo il verbo di un avverbio, come nella frase

> *desiderava **ardentemente** di rivedere la famiglia*

in cui tra l'infinito e il *desiderava* troviamo l'avverbio ***ardentemente***, fatto che rende di aiuto nella lettura ricollegare l'infinito al verbo desiderare e che a questo punto non suona più ridondante nel linguaggio parlato.